# Apache php5-fpm virtualhost no input file specified

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, virtualhost, mod-fastcgi

I am trying to set up Roundcube Mail as a virtualhost on a subdomain at my webserver.

The server is a virtual host running Ubuntu, Apache 2, php-fpm

The problem:

- Roundcube mail works when accessing it directly trough the IP: http://213.179.57.118/roundcubemail/

  - Originally roundcubemail redirects everything to "/php5-fcgi", I have amended this with a redirect in .htaccess: `RewriteRule ^php5-fcgi$ index.php`
- Roundcube does not work as expected on http://webmail.munso.no (try logging in with any username/password)

  - It again redirects everything to "/php5-fcgi" and seems to ignore all .htaccess settings, so the redirect doesnt work
- A test php file works as expected: http://webmail.munso.no/test.php, so php works as intended

My vhost config for webmail.munso.no:

/etc/apache2/sites-available/webmail.conf (this site is enabled):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName webmail.munso.no
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/roundcubemail

        <Directory /var/www/roundcubemail>
                Options All
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                Require all granted

                # Cache control
                <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$">
                        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
                </FilesMatch>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fastcgi.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
   AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp5 .php
   Action application/x-httpd-fastphp5 /php5-fcgi
   Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
   FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 360
   <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

The main issue, I think, is that for some reason Roundcubemail redirects all php code to /php5-fpm. As mentioned, a .htaccess rewrite hack works on the direct IP link, but will not "fire" when accessing the subdomain.

I cannot get my head around this, and have been searching and trying for about 3 hours now..

Comment: Why have you configured roundcube to use `/php5-fcgi` path? That should be transparent for the browser - that path should be used only as internal apache redirect and not in roundcube / html / browser.

Comment: I havent configured roudcude to use that path. It came that way... I had the same problem when trying to set up magento, but then i just gave up.